# DOMDocument save at the same time

Tags: php, domdocument, fopen

I am using `file_get_contents()` then `DOMDocument::loadXML` and it's `save()` method to update an XML on the server in every ~1 hour (if somebody visits the page). My question is, what would happen if the `save()` method is called by two user at the same time? Is there some lock automatically? Should I change everything and use the `fopen()`, `flock()`, etc. methods?

Comment: If your XML is global and does not get affected by the user called your script, then i would just set something, a flag (etc. a file or a database row) that my XML is being written. Then a parallel user should read for the existence of this flag and don't try to rewrite what being written. Based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967707/how-to-lock-a-xml-file-usinf-flock) question, i assume _DOMDocument_ doesn't lock the files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What happens if 2 users checks flag at the same time? Could that be that both get the rights to write the file?

Comment: Indeed but percentage of this would be rather minimal. Consider the time required for building a whole XML and 1) updating a database row 2) or creating just an empty file (flag). The difference in both (XML creation vs 2 examples) might be huge but strictly speaking, if you _don't want both_ to execute the code, you should lock. Its safely to lock anyway since you're not make use of any user and just write an XML. The problem would occur if you wanted to use some information from user. Then locking would simply IGNORE the second user.